# A more elegant way of using Reactjs to redirect a page without setTimout and causing Warning: setState(...): Can only update

Tags: reactjs, redirect, redux

I have a simple react + redux login page. When auth is successful i redirect the user to home page. This initially brought up an issues of "Warning: setState(...): Can only update...". After searching around, a proposed solution was to setTimeout on the redirect function to give a small delay in order for the states to be set.

I am looking for a more elegant way to redirect a user without using setTimeout as it can be a little unpredictable depending on situation and without causing "setState(...)" warning .

Below is a condensed version of the code:

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     //...
    };
  }

  render() {
    let {isLoginSuccess } = this.props;
     return (
     <div><form>
     //...
      {isLoginSuccess && (
        <div>Success {(setTimeout(() => this.goHome()), 1)}</div>
      )}
     </form></div>
     );
  }

goHome = function() {
  this.props.history.push('/');
};
```

Comment: What do you want to do? you only are giving a 1ms timeout to redirect, do you want to redirect as soon as login is a success or wait for some time

Comment: timeout is never a good solution. Either redirect should be on some event like login successfull or inside callback method of setState.

Comment: I would like to redirect as soon login is success without setState warning @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: I have an action file that contains login request and login dispatcher, I have tried previous  to place redirect code, allthought i did not find a way to access this.props.history.

`function login(...){return dispatch=>{sendLogin(...).then(success=>{if (success){..do something...}})}}`

Comment: If you use React Router v4, you can use a `<Redirect>` component, basically you set your stated to 'logged in', which causes a re-render, and in your render method if the state is logged in you render the `<Redirect>` component

Comment: is `isLoginSuccess ` a promise? Make the click handler its own function and use `.then` or `async/await` syntax to ensure login finishes before redirecting. Don't use `setTimeout`. I can show you how to handle your issue with `setTimeout` if you truly want to, but it's bad practice and you really shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `isLoginSuccess` is a prop, you could check for it in `componentWillReceiveProps` function and `redirect` from there

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     //...
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
       const {isLoginSuccess} = this.props;
       if(!isLoginSuccess && nextProps.isLoginSuccess) {
          this.props.history.push('/');
       }
  }
  render() {
    let {isLoginSuccess } = this.props;
     return (
     <div><form>
     //...
      {isLoginSuccess && (
        <div>Success </div>
      )}
     </form></div>
     );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using React-Router, you can rewrite your code to use other life-cycle events, specifically `componentDidMount` to do this. Do not cause any state changes in `render`.

Example:

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     //...
    };
  }

  goHome() {
    this.props.history.push('/');
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    let {isLoginSuccess } = this.props;
    if (isLoginSuccess){
        this.goHome();
    }
  }

  render() {
    let {isLoginSuccess } = this.props;
     return (
     <div><form>
     //...
      {isLoginSuccess && (
        <div>Logged-in successfully, please wait while we take you to home...</div>
      )}
     </form></div>
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: The solution did not work as componentDidMount() was executed only once on page load. It was not re executed when login action was executed unless there is a specific way to re trigger it.

Comment: I am using a router "react-router-dom" : { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch }.

Comment: Yes, cwrp will better fit this.